# Remove commenting in CKEditor 4

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I write in the code  And when I switch to the visual editor, then '' to '?-->'. How do I remove it? I want to use PHP and other languages in the CKEditor.

Sorry for my English. I'm from Ukraine. ;]

Example:
[image]

Switch to the visual editor and back.
[image]

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: Yes. I added an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this config:

```
config.protectedSource.push( /<\?[\s\S]*?\?>/g );   // PHP code
```

Taken from [here](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html#.protectedSource). CKEditor should ignore your PHP code then.